# How do I use fabric.js with Meteor using the script tag?

Tags: javascript, meteor, fabricjs

I'm new to Meteor. I've managed to make some simple programs using both Meteor and Fabric.js, but now that I'm trying to use them both together I can't get it to work.

I'm including Fabric.js by using a script tag in the head of the main html file, but when I call fabric.Canvas from my client JS it doesn't recognize the library. The error that I get in the Firefox JS console is "ReferenceError: fabric is not defined". I placed the js file in my public directory.

I've looked around on SO and saw threads about including node modules, but I simply want to use the js file instead of including a whole module. I did find a project on GitHub that uses the script tag without a problem: https://github.com/6/realtime-fabric  I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript so perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't think he's doing anything different from me. Any help that you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add a 'client' directory to your project and place the fabric.js file in there. Meteor bundles the files in this directory and sends them to the client. You should not need to use a script tag in your HTML.

http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you said but I still get the same error. Edit: Oops, I didn't realize that enter would post the message... I have var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'); in my client/client.js file. I tried putting that line in Meteor.startup in client.js, but that causes my browser to hang.

Comment: Try putting your fabric code inside `Template.myTemplate.rendered = function () {...};` in client.js

Comment: I get a variety of errors now: https://gist.github.com/muraiki/29ce819bbf6319e014cc  (I've included a link to the project as the gist title) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was unclear in that last comment. Keep `fabric.js` in a separate file in your `client` directory. Your demo code (starting with `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');`) should go in `Template.board.rendered`.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I did try that before, but trying it again I have the same result: the browser hangs while it eats up ever greater amounts of memory. :( I ended up moving to Raphael.js, although the problem there is that the canvas I create in Template.board.rendered can't be accessed from other functions (like .observeChanges on a collection). But that's another question for a different thread. Thank you for all of your help; it seems like I might have to report this as a bug to either Meteor or Fabric.js, but I don't know how to trace down which is the culprit.

Comment: If you place fabric.js or all.js into client/compatibility folder then it works.